# How to animate a search box in android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm wondering if it's possible to animate a search item in action bar. Currently when I touch it, it just collapses. But I want it to collapse with a nice animation.

I googled this but I didn't find anything.

this is my search menu item :

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my questions? Why is no one answering?

Comment: Been a while, but https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html is what you want

Answer (score 0):

I am using slide from right to left animation, when tap on search icon in actionbar searchview will open from right to left animtion, you can apply any view 
 in **view:View** to animate while calling **slideFromRightToLeft(view: View)**

Please check the following code, its in kotlin, you can covert it into java

```
private fun slideFromRightToLeft(view: View) {
    var animate = TranslateAnimation(view.width.toFloat(),0f, 0f, 0f);
    animate.duration = 100
    animate.fillAfter = true
    view.startAnimation(animate)
}
```

Comment: i tested with toolbar and actionbar also, both working fine as expected